# I don't understand what aggregate function is and how it applies to my query

Tags: sql

I'm stuck on this assignment and I don't understand why my query does not output data when I include `city` and `grade`.
This is the question:

> Display the total purchase of each customer, including the customers’ name, city, and grade.

[This is the original table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sulmb.png)

My answer is:

```
SELECT cust_name,city,grade,SUM(purch_amt)
FROM customer, orders
GROUP BY cust_name
WHERE customer.cust_id = orders.customer_id;
```

This displays an error that says

> Your query does not include the specified expression 'city' as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: Do not post images of tables. Post the respective `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements. [Edit] your question to do so. Also tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: The error message describes exactly what is happening.  You've asked to see the count in buckets grouped by `cust_name,city and grade` but you've not specified `city` or `grade` in your `group by`.  So you just add `city` & `grade`.  But to understand why, you need to ask what would you expect to see if your query did execute?  It won't make sense.

Comment: `WHERE` also needs to be before `GROUP BY`. Look at sample queries online and you'll see this

Comment: Aggregate functions (AVG(), SUM(), MIN(), MAX()) are functions that aggregate (collect) multiple rows into a single row. The error is because all columns that are not being aggregated must be in the `GROUP BY` clause, and you've not done that, which is precisely what the error message is telling you. You've grouped by only the `cust_name`, but your `SELECT` also contains `city` and `grade`, which are not in that `GROUP BY` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SELECT` and `FROM` appear to be ok, your `GROUP BY` however needs to also have `city` and `grade` (along with `cust_name`). The `GROUP BY` clause also needs to be below the `WHERE` clause.

The final code should therefore look like this:

```
SELECT cust_name, city, grade, SUM(purch_amt)
FROM customer, orders
WHERE customer.cust_id = orders.customer_id;
GROUP BY cust_name, city, grade
```

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT c.cust_name, c.city, c.grade, SUM(o.purch_amt)
FROM customer c JOIN
     orders o
     on c.cust_id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY c.cust_name, c.city, c.grade;
```

Note that I've added table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.  Also, the  `GROUP BY` columns are consistent with the unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.